# Magento 2 - Minicart not updated after login from authentication popup

Tags: magento2, cart, quote, quoteitem

As guest, i add  **product 1** to cart. Then i go to cart page and login to my account using authentication popup.

Lets assume that my account have a **product 2** in cart. So after login we should see **product 1** and **product 2** in minicart, meanwhile that appear here is just **product 1**.

Then when i trying to remove **product 1** item from minicart, show message **'We can't find the quote item.'** and minicart turn out to be as it should be (displaying both products).

So, is there any solution to my problem? Feedback is very appreciated.

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Magento 2.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem by following this issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7500

Comment: Have you fixed the issue already? If so please post here.